# Save switch state android

Tags: android

Hello i don't know how can i let my app save switch state
Example:
I want open the app and i want switch off the switch after restart my app i want my app keep the states off and vice versa

```
public class AlgeriaNotificationsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private TextView switchStatus;
private Switch mySwitch;

private static final String TAG = "AlgeriaNotificationsActivity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_algeria_notifications);

    switchStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.switchStatus);
    mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("switchkey", false);
    mySwitch.setChecked(silent);

    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
            }else{
                switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
            }
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("switchkey", isChecked);
        }
    });

    //check the current state before we display the screen
    if(mySwitch.isChecked()){
        switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
    }
    else {
        switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences for same, when switch is check event occur just save its value to true else set false.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

in activity oncreate just check fro sharedprefernce value if it is true set switch on else set off

oncreate check for switch value

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("switchkey", false);
   mySwitch.setChecked(silent);
```

code for save state in switch checkchange

```
 @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){
                switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently ON");
            }else{
                switchStatus.setText("Switch is currently OFF");
            }
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("switchkey", isChecked);
 editor.commit();
        }
```

Comment: thank you for help i don't know how can i do that please can you show me "in activity oncreate just check fro sharedprefernce value if it is true set switch on else set off"

Comment: it's still not saving the changes

Comment: @Edward sorry was my mistake i dint commit change in onCheckedChanged please check edited answer  editor.commit(); was missed

Comment: glad it helped, if it worked for you can accept this as answer :)

Comment: thanks a lot it's working but please where can add this action FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("tools");

Comment: @Edward please add new question with relevant code and description

Comment: Please how can i duplicate the switch button

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737173/how-i-can-duplicate-the-switch-button-with-sharedprefernce